# Need quick help : How to do database assertions for output that we got like null, not null, contains, assert using karate frmework

Tags: karate

I have ran db query and i got the below json response

*def dataset = databaseMethods.runJsonQuery(result, query)
Then print dataset

output :
[{"Account no :"123", "Key" : "9989"}, {"Account no :"345", "Key" : "9889"},{"Account no :"569", "Key" : "9989"}]

And now i want to do assertions like notnull, null , present etc for each and each and value in output

eg : I wrote below one but its not working , i think i am doing wrong can you correct me and let me know how i can diff assertions and i have gone through documentation but still confused in using

Then match dataset contains [Account no:'notnull']

checkpoints i have to do : Account no should not be null and key should be not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special characters in JSON keys need special handling:

```
Then match dataset contains { 'Account no': '#notnull', Key: '#string' }
```

Also please read this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#schema-validation